# how to create multiple data in mongoose something like this?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

what is the best way to insert many records into model? inserMany or create if the data was array of the object ?

I have **Model** like this

```
    questions = {  
               questions: String, 
               category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 
                         "Category" }]
                 }

    category = { name: String, 
                 questions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 
                           "questions" }] 
                }
```

so if the request inputs the category has multiple in array  something like this ['book', 'movie', 'clothes'], how to record this category to create only once in mongoose and I want that category `IDS`, `$push or $addToSet` into  `category in question model` ?

one more, how to make sure that categories are unique ? so the category which are duplicate can't be create ?

Comment: Seems Confusing! You want to push category and in the category collection and take all those category _ids and push in question collection! On what based, category _id should push in questions collection or is it like only one document is there..in question collection?

Comment: i want to push id's of categories into questions categories so i can make it populate in questions, i try to make cloning StackOverflow schema, is that possible to create the multiple records but avoid the duplicate ?

Comment: can you show how should be end output?
the confusing part is model show question in category model and category in questions model.!Add some sample data!
and  To avoid duplicate can be achieved by a createing unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Your models are wrong. First, you correct your models. For example:

```
questions = {  
  questionName: String, 
  category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" }]
}

category = { 
  name: String
}
```

Then after if you want to come Selected Category questions. You write a select query.